# Windows 8 APP : Store data

Tags: c#, windows-8

What is the best way to store data for a Windows 8 APP ? 
I need to store from one to thousands of little pictures (max 300x300px) (Load from FilePicker).
Also, is there a recommended practice to store picture (A class rather than an other) ?w

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are all of the pictures the same size? There is a solution for that. If they are different sizes then there is another solution. Please specific more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing 1000 of images uncompressed in memory could hang computer, depending on images and memory available. So that's not the best practice.

You haven't mentioned why you need to do this, so there is no clear solution, but some guidelines:

- if you need to show many pics on screen, use XAML (e.g. Image element) and set path to the image on web or local disk. Windows will do the caching for you. Also, put Image element in GridView or ListView and use Data binding
- if you afraid that images might get lost and it is not enough to keep just path, copy them in ApplicationData LocalFolder.
- if you need to do some operations on images, then load into memory the one you need or load them one by one.

Comment: Thank you ! You are right, I forgot to mention that I need to store it permanently (to retrieve it on the app's reload) and to read it pixel by pixel. So I need to retrieve my pics from a database (Which one ? That is my question) and load it memory.
So the Image Element can retrieve a pic from its path ? There is no access problems because of Windows 8 application restriction ? Can I retrieve a bitmap from this Image Element ? In that case I might save only the pic's path and retrieve the whole pic by this way.

Comment: Your app must have access to path, remember to ask Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList to make access that user gave you by FilePicker permanent.

If you copy to local ApplicationData folder, it is always accessible.

Images are not stored in general databases, there are some specific databases that could be used for this, but they probably don't work on Win8.